# rsync error on Downloading

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, rsync

I am trying to setup a Rsyncmirror on my mount drive `/mnt/Mirror/ubuntu_mirror`, so I am trying the command:

```
rsync -a --bwlimit=128 rsync://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu /mnt/Mirror/ubuntu_mirror
```

but it shows an error:

```
rsync: getaddrinfo: archive.ubuntu.com 873: Name or service not known
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(122) [Receiver=3.0.9]
```

Comment: can you ping archive.ubuntu.com ?

Comment: I'm thinking that the error listing combines the lines from before and after you fixed the dns issue, and only the latter is now valid?  The command you are using works for me.  Can you add '-vvvv' to the rsync options to get some more info on where it is failing?  Also can you test your network connectivity with `nmap -p rsync archive.ubuntu.com`?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by the wrong DNS server.

If the device is use static ip, make sure you set the right "Domain name server".

If the device is use dynamic ip, make sure the device get the right "Domain name server".

Edit: check `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: I add my proxy ip on /etc/resolv.conf and tryed with above command but now I am facing a new problem                                   rsync: failed to connect to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.92.177): Connection refused (111)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(122) [Receiver=3.0.9]
can anyone suggest me ??    Thank U..

Comment: What's this about a proxy?  (If you are trying to connect via a proxy, that's important info that needs to be in your question).

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter a valid dns server in `/etc/resolv.conf`. Try 4.4.4.4, or opendns's available on their website in the footer.